# Override DRF Serializer from reusable app

Tags: django-rest-framework

Is there an obvious way that I'm missing to override the Serializer that DRF uses for a viewset from within a reusable app?

I have a `ViewSet` that uses a `ModelSerializer` subclass. I want to add a field to it.
However, I want to put the model and everything else related to this external field into a separate app, because it is not part of the core functionality.

The separate app can depend on the app in the core Django project, but not vice-versa. Obviously it's not really reusable but let's still use this term for simplicity.

So for a contrived example let's say I have a simple `Employee` model in an app in the core project, and I want to add a "reusable" app that allows to store employee's Facebook profiles.
So I would have the following models, viewsets and serializers in the "core_app":

`models.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

`viewsets.py`

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Employee
from .serializers import EmployeeSerializer


class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```

`serializers.py`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Employee


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source="user.username")

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ["username", "department"]
```

Now I have a reusable app that has a model with a `OneToOneField` to the `Employee` model, and a serializer subclass that adds the desired field:

`models.py`

```py
from django.db import models

from core_app.models import Employee


class FacebookProfile(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    facebook_profile_link = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

`serializers.py`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from core_app.models import Employee
from core_app.serializers import EmployeeSerializer


class FacebookProfileEmployeeSerializer(EmployeeSerializer):
    facebook_profile_link = serializers.CharField(source="facebookprofile")

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ["username", "department", "facebook_profile_link"]
```

So basically I want to make `core_app.viewsets.EmployeeViewSet`  use `FacebookProfileEmployeeSerializer` from the "reusable" app instead of `core_app.serializers.EmployeeSerializer`.
I don't want to have to make any changes to `core_app`, neither to the Django project (apart from adding the "reusable" app to `INSTALLED_SETTINGS`).

I could override the complete `core_app.viewsets.EmployeeViewSet` in my "reusable" app and then use it over the original one by overriding the URLs in `ROOT_URLCONF`, but that's not a nice solution and would require me to change the project.

Another obvious solution to only replace the serializer that `core_app.viewsets.EmployeeViewSet` uses would be monkey patching. I would like to avoid that if possible, because it's a hacky solution that might lead to maintainability issues and also because it will probably also require me to change the project, to patch the serializer before the original is imported.

So if there is a more explicit way to do it I would prefer that.
I tried to find a better approach but couldn't find any so far.

Answer (score 1):

> override the complete core_app.viewsets.EmployeeViewSet in my "reusable" app and then use it over the original one by overriding the URLs in ROOT_URLCONF, but that's not a nice solution and would require me to change the project.

I would recommend that:

`facebook/viewsets.py`:

```py
from core_app.viewsets import EmployeeViewSet

from .serializers import FacebookProfileEmployeeSerializer

class FacebookProfileEmployeeViewSet(EmployeeViewSet):
    serializer_class = FacebookProfileEmployeeSerializer
```

Then in `urls.py`

```
# Note that we use FacebookProfileEmployeeViewSet in preference to EmployeeViewSet
router.register(r"employee", FacebookProfileEmployeeViewSet)
```

I think it is very common for a third party app to require a 2-step install of:

1. add the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings
2. add the URLs to `urls.py`